# SQL Server tsql parenthesis logic?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, logic

(dynamic query...)

```
select * from myTable where

(   <--- 

 @param1 IS NULL
                  OR (
                         param1 IN 
                                           ( 
                                              SELECT item
                                              FROM   blabla1
                                           )
                     )
)   <---
and
(   <---

 @param2 IS NULL
                  OR (
                         param2  IN 
                                           ( 
                                              SELECT item
                                              FROM   blabla2
                                           )
                     )
)   <---
```

question :

look at the parenthesis marked with `<---`.

Can I remove them ( without impacting the logic here ) ?

Comment: IMHO Better to have unnecessary parentheses and more readable/understable logic than to do a mistake in logic. You may suggest yourself that order of logic operations works another way than MSSQL works in fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. you need those but you can remove the ones around the `IN` statement.

```
select * 
from myTable
where
  (@param1 IS NULL OR @param1 IN (SELECT item FROM blabla1))
  and 
  (@param2 IS NULL OR @param2 IN (SELECT item FROM blabla2))
```

If you remove the ones you asked about you would have a query that works like this

```
select * 
from myTable
where
  param1 IS NULL
  OR
  (param1 IN (SELECT item FROM blabla1)) and param2 IS NULL 
  OR
  (param2 IN (SELECT item FROM blabla2))
```

Answer (score 1):

@MikaelEriksson is right, the results will not be the same, because the AND operator has higher precedence over the OR operator ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx)).

In your sample, instead of `(A or A') and (B or B')`, you'll get `A or (A' and B) or B'`.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot remove them. If we remove these brackets then it will impact the logic.